# Buttons wont appear when added to JLabel containing buffered image

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, layout-manager

So I have a buffered image loaded onto a `JLabel`.

When I launch the program only the image shows, but not the buttons.

I've tried adding the `JButtons` directly to the `JLabel` with the same results. However, if I add the `buttonPanel` directly to the frame the buttons end up being visible. If I, however, add the `JLabel` directly to the frame and then add the `buttonPanel`, only the buttons are visible.

```
public void setProp(){
    //frame properties
    mainFrame.setSize(1200, 845); //JFrame
    mainFrame.setVisible(false);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //layout properties
    buttonLayout.setHgap(100); //GridLayout
    buttonLayout.setColumns(1);
    buttonLayout.setRows(6);

    //panel properties
    buttonPanel.setLayout(buttonLayout);
    buttonPanel.setVisible(true);
    buttonPanel.setOpaque(false);


    //button properties
    newGame.setOpaque(false);
    newGame.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    newGame.setBorderPainted(false);
    newGame.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    newGame.setFont(buttonFont);
    newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //launch designated method
        }
    });

    loadGame.setOpaque(false);
    loadGame.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    loadGame.setBorderPainted(false);
    loadGame.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    loadGame.setFont(buttonFont);
    loadGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //launch designated method
        }
    });

    credits.setOpaque(false);
    credits.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    credits.setBorderPainted(false);
    credits.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    credits.setFont(buttonFont);
    credits.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //launch designated method
        }
    });

    exit.setOpaque(false);
    exit.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    exit.setBorderPainted(false);
    exit.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    exit.setFont(buttonFont);
    exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    //background properties
    background = importPic("D:/programming rescources/strategy game/resources/images/mmpic.JPG");

    //adding components to mainFrame
    buttonPanel.add(newGame); //adding all buttons onto JPanel with GridLayout
    buttonPanel.add(loadGame);
    buttonPanel.add(credits);
    buttonPanel.add(exit);

    background.add(buttonPanel);//this is the JLabel with the buffered image

    mainFrame.add(background);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved the issue. I did it by adding a BorderLayout to the backgorund (JLabel), and then adding the background to the JFrame.